# Regex for a string used for save a telephone number

Tags: php, regex, php-5.3, regex-negation, php-5.5

I have a question. How should look a regex for the following words:
+23456745678 or +29845281058, (with comma)
I tried but no result:

```
if (!preg_match('#^\+[0-9]{11}$#',$string)) {
                    return ("Msisdn $string is incorrect!");
                    break;
                }
```

Always I get this error.
Please help me. Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern should be:

```
'/\+[0-9]{11},?/'
```

The ^ in the beginning and $ at the end stand for beginning and end of line, which I am not sure if you really want there (my guess is not).

Test it here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/78v

Another option is to use \d for digit

```
'/\+\d{11},?/'
```

Comment: sorry forgot the comma